# Upgrading pip appears to only install the current version (8.1) even when 18 is available

Tags: python, python-2.7, pip

I'm trying to upgrade pip on an Ubuntu machine running Python 2.7. I want to do this for the current user only, hence I am using the following command:

```
python2 -m pip install --upgrade --user
```

As per best practices, I'm using `python2 pip install` instead of just `pip install` i.e. https://packaging.python.org/guides/installing-using-pip-and-virtualenv/

So far so good. Pip now appears to fetch `pip-18.1 (pip-18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl)` and installs. However, the console reports that it has only installed pip-8.1.1 (see below).

```
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c2/d7/90f34cb0d83a6c5631cf71dfe64cc1054598c843a92b400e55675cc2ac37/pip-18.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (1.3MB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 1.3MB 31.1MB/s 
Installing collected packages: pip
Successfully installed pip-8.1.1

You are using pip version 8.1.1, however version 18.1 is available.
```

What has gone wrong here? Why is Pip only reinstalling the current pip version?

---

(Notes on why I think I need pip-18)

```
Collecting ipython>=4.0.0 (from ipykernel==4.10)
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/42/bb/0ed1fb1d57d697326f9e9b827d9a74b81dee56031ed7c252bc716195ad7a/ipython-7.2.0.tar.gz (5.1MB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 5.1MB 149kB/s 
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:

IPython 7.0+ supports Python 3.5 and above.
When using Python 2.7, please install IPython 5.x LTS Long Term Support version.
Python 3.3 and 3.4 were supported up to IPython 6.x.

See IPython `README.rst` file for more information:

    https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/README.rst

Python sys.version_info(major=2, minor=7, micro=12, releaselevel='final', serial=0) detected.
Your pip version is out of date, please install pip >= 9.0.1. pip 8.1.1 detected.
```

Comment: Hello @JohnL_10 did you get the solution yet?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately!